# Gnus with maildir : strange fields in reply header

Tags: emacs, gnus, maildir

I am using Gnus with Offlineimap to read GMail. Offlineimap fetches the mail from GMail and stores in in Maildir folders on my local machine at **/mnt/Mail/** . I point Gnus to these folders, from where it reads the mail and displays it to me.

When I try to reply to a mail (by typing 'r' when the cursor is on the mail's subject in the Summary buffer), I get the following problems:

(i) The "Fcc:" field is populated with a non-existant directory, and I am told that this directory does not exist (it does not). I am also prompted whether I want to create this  directory as a new maildir directory:

> **/mnt/Mail/sent** is not a maildir. Create it? (y or n)

Since I don't want to save a local copy of the sent message (because Gmail SMTP and IMAP will get it for me anyway), I have to always say "no" before proceeding. This is a huge inconvenience when it happens every time.

**How do I get rid of this field?** I *do not* want to save sent mails anywhere on my local machine in this manner.

I have tried the following settings in my **.gnus** file, but to no avail:

> (setq gnus-author-copy nil)
>   (setq gnus-author-copy-saver nil)

..

> (setq mail-yank-ignored-headers "Fcc:")

(ii) There is a "References:" field in the message header which says something like:

> References: <87ty8n1qbz.fsf@mylocalmachine.localdomain>

**How do I get rid of this field?** This looks ugly, and quite useless in normal emails.

(iii) The "From:" field in the message header refers to my local machine:

> From: G Philip <gphilip@mylocalmachine.localdomain>

I have to edit this field also every time so that it contains my proper email
address.

Since I use a couple of email addresses with my gmail account, I have tried the following in my .gnus file to get this field to use the "To:" address of the email to which I am replying, but neither approach works:

> (setq message-alternative-emails
>                  (regexp-opt '("myfirstaddress@gmail.com" "myotheraddress@gmail.com")))

..

> (setq gnus-posting-styles
>         '(((header "to" "myfirstaddress  gmail.com")
>            (address "myfirstaddress  gmail.com"))
>           ((header "to" "myotheraddress  gmail.com")
>            (address "myotheraddress  gmail.com"))))

**How do I set things up so that the "From:" field automatically gets filled with the "To:" field of the original email?**

My .gnus file looks like this:

> ;; Use Gnus to read gmail from the local directory to which offlineimap syncs
>
> (setq gnus-select-method
>
> ```
>  '(nnmaildir "Gmail"
>
>              (directory "/mnt/Mail")
>
>              (expire-age never)))
> ```
>
> ;; Don't hide read email
>
> (setq gnus-fetch-old-headers t)
>
> ;; Sort by date, newest first.
>
> (setq gnus-thread-sort-functions
>
> ```
>        '(gnus-thread-sort-by-number
>
>          gnus-thread-sort-by-most-recent-date))
> ```
>
> ;; Do not look for new "groups" every time.
>
> (setq gnus-check-new-newsgroups nil)
>
> ;; Use the better (but slower) function to extract information
>
> ;; from mail headers.
>
> (setq gnus-extract-address-components
>
> ```
>  'mail-extract-address-components)
> ```
>
> ;; Use the gmail SMTP server to send email.
>
> (setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
>
> ```
>   message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
>
>   smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
>
>   smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 "myemailaddress@gmail.com" nil))
>
>   smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
>
>   smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
>
>   smtpmail-smtp-service 587
>
>   smtpmail-debug-info t
>
>   smtpmail-local-domain "gmail.com")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, (ii) is easy enough. You can hide any header by adding it to `gnus-ignored-headers` (or by removing it from `gnus-visible-headers`, if it's there). See http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_142.html#SEC142

(iii) may also be easy, if I understand the question correctly. Are you talking about the From field in a message that you are sending? If so, then set `user-mail-address` to whatever value you want to use by default and Gnus won't have to guess based on your username and your machine's hostname.

Comment: Thank you, but this is already the case: gnus-visible-headers is non-nil:

"^From:\\|^Newsgroups:\\|^Subject:\\|^Date:\\|^Followup-To:\\|^Reply-To:\\|^Organization:\\|^Summary:\\|^Keywords:\\|^To:\\|^[BGF]?Cc:\\|^Posted-To:\\|^Mail-Copies-To:\\|^Mail-Followup-To:\\|^Apparently-To:\\|^Gnus-Warning:\\|^Resent-From:\\|^X-Sent:"



, and, FWIW, gnus-ignored-headers contains a reference to "References" :



("^Path:" "^Expires:" "^Date-Received:" "^References:" "^Xref:" ...)



But that doesn't seem to deter gnus!

Comment: `gnus-ignored-headers` should be a single string containing a regex, the same style as `gnus-visible-headers`. However, this doesn't matter because `gnus-ignored-headers` is only used if `gnus-visible-headers` is nil. You might double-check the value of `gnus-visible-headers` by going to your message buffer and doing `C-h v gnus-visible-headers`. That'll show you the current value (as well as the documentation for the variable).

Comment: Double-checking the value of `gnus-visible-headers` in the manner you suggested gave the exact same result as before. I have resigned to deleting the pesky `Fcc:` field every time.